# Optimize CSV processing script - Python, Perl, and Java

Tags: java, python, perl, parsing, csv

I am trying to make a simple scrip that quickly process a noisy CSV file.
I just want to grab a few columns from a large CSV file (gzipped) and write a new CSV file with the trimmed data. Also added one simple filtering method that checks the length of columns[0] == 15.

I have compared perl, java, and python scripts and found Java is much faster than other languages. I am wondering if there is any other way that can optimize this simple process for each language?

Benchmark time for each language is (for 800MByte gzip file)
1. Java: 74sec
2. Python: 197sec
3. Perl: 7 min

Python:

```
import gzip
import csv
import time

def getArray(row): 
    columns = [0,4,5,26,33,34,35,36,39,41,42,47,54,65,66,72,73,91]
    row_filt = []
    for i in columns:
        row_filt.append(row[i])
    return row_filt

filename = 'Very_large_csv.gz' 
outfile = filename + '.csv'
csv.register_dialect('wifi', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar = '')
start_time = time.time()

try:
    f = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    f2 = open(outfile, 'wb')
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = 'wifi')
    writer = csv.writer(f2, dialect = 'wifi')
    header = reader.next()
    writer.writerow(getArray(header))
    for row in reader:
        if (len(row[0]) != 15):
            continue
        writer.writerow(getArray(row))
    print(time.time() - start_time)

finally:
    f.close()
```

Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my @COLUMNS = (0,4,5,26,33,34,35,36,39,41,42,47,54,65,66,72,73,91);

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({  binary => 1,
                                sep_char => '|',
                                escape_char => undef,
                                eol => "\n",
                                quote_char => undef
                                });

my $infile='Very_large_csv.gz';

my $fh = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new($infile) or die "IO::Uncompress::Gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

my $outfile = $infile . ".csv";
open my $out, ">", $outfile or die "$outfile: $!\n";

my @header_row = split(/\|/,<$fh>);
my @header = ();
foreach my $column (@COLUMNS)
{
    push @header, $header_row[$column];
}
my $header_filter = \@header;   
$csv->print ($out, $header_filter);

print "Start.\n";
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh))
{
    length($row->[0]) == 15 or next;
    my @data = ();
    foreach my $column (@COLUMNS)
    {
        push @data, $row->[$column];
    }
    my $row_filter = \@data;

    $csv->print($out, $row_filter); 
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag ();

close $fh;
close $out or die "$outfile: $!";
```

Java:

```
public class NoiseFilter {
    static final int[] columns = {0,4,5,26,33,34,35,36,39,41,42,47,54,65,66,72,73,91};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        fname='Very_large_csv.gz';
        GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzip));

        String line = reader.readLine(); // Header
        String[] header = line.split("\\|");
        PrintWriter ww = new PrintWriter(fname + ".csv");
        printRow(header, ww);

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split("\\|",-1);
            if (data[0].length() != 15 ) { continue; }
            printRow(data, ww);
        }

        ww.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    private static void printRow(String[] row, PrintWriter writer) {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                writer.print(row[columns[i]]);
            } else {
                writer.print("|" + row[columns[i]]);
            }
        }

        writer.print("\n");
    }
}
```

I have modified the python code as follows and got 95sec runtime, which is comperable to Java.

```
def getArray(line): 
    string=''
    row=line.split(',')
    for i in columns:   
        string+=(row[i]+',')
    return string+'\n'

try:
    f = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    f2 = open(outfile, 'wb')

    header = f.readline() 
    f2.write(getArray(header))

    for line in f:
        f2.write(getArray(line))
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: I have changed python without using csv reader. Using "row=line.split('|')" and concatenating string "s+=(row[i]+'|')", the run time has reduced to 112 seconds, which is comparable to java.

Answer (score 9):

Certain things could be optimized in your Perl script. For example, this:

```
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh))
{
    length($row->[0]) == 15 or next;
    my @data = ();
    foreach my $column (@COLUMNS)
    {
        push @data, $row->[$column];
    }
    my $row_filter = \@data;

    $csv->print($out, $row_filter); 
}
```

Could be replaced by:

```
my $row;
length($row->[0])==15 and $csv->print($out, [ @{$row}[@COLUMNS] ])
    while $row = $csv->getline($fh);
```

... which should perform somewhat better. I've not benchmarked it, but it's unlikely to make a *huge* difference.

More importantly, the reason your Java code is faster is that it's *doing much less*. Text::CSV_XS (and I guess the Python module you use too) is a full parser - it handles quoted fields, escaped characters, etc. Consider the following pipe-delimited file, which is intended to be two rows and two columns:

```
1|"Foo+Bar"
2|"Foo|Bar"
```

Your Java code naively splits lines on pipes, meaning that "Foo|Bar" which should be a single atomic string value, instead gets split into two fields. If the Java code did the same checks that the Perl and Python versions are doing, it would slow right down.

Conversely, you could probably speed up the Perl or Python version by abandoning proper CSV-style parsing, and just using `split`. e.g. in Perl:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split /\|/;
    length $F[0] == 15 or next;
    print {$out} join("|", @F[@COLUMNS]), "\n";
}
```

Your entire script could even by done using the following one-liner:

```
gzip -d -c Very_large_csv.gz | perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join("|", @F[0,4,5,26,33,34,35,36,39,41,42,47,54,65,66,72,73,91]) if $. == 1 || length($F[0]) == 15' > output.csv
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-F`: `split()` pattern for `-a` switch (//'s are optional)
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `gzip -d -c Very_large_csv.gz`: Decompresses file, pipes it to STDOUT
- `print join("|", @F[0,4,5,26,33,34,35,36,39,41,42,47,54,65,66,72,73,91])`: Keep only certain indexes of CSV file
- `if $. == 1 || length($F[0]) == 15`: Filter based off header or first column

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of fat in your inner loop. In the python version you constructng a new columns object each time you call getarray(). Since the getarray() function itself is pretty simple, you could in-line the whole thing.

Unlikely to be a significan speedup.

You could also try PyPy, which might make a relatively large difference -- probably still not as fast as the Java version though.

Comment: I have changed the code using "line.split(',')" and tried pypy, but pypy seems slower than generic python.